# how to bind knockout's Observable array length to an html element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Supose I have the following viewmodel

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.fruits = ko.observableArray(["Apple", "banana", "orange"]);
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I want to be able to do something like this to bind the observable array's length on the html like any other viewmodel property.

```
<span data-bind="text: fruits.length"></span>
```

For this purpuse, I tried converting observable array to simple array, but with no success

```
span data-bind="text: fruits().length"></span>
```

I understand this should be easy and therefore must be missing something. Could you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: check that there are no errors in the debug console of your browser.  also check out http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what problem you're having but this works fine:

```
<span data-bind="text: fruits().length"></span>
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7gST7/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to discover the cause of the problem. In my original code I had the following

```
<span data-bind:"text= venues().length"></span>
```

using colon instead of equal sign for the html. As Martin Booth pointed, everything else was correct.